# With AFNetworking how can I read the error message contained in request.responseString

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

```
NSLog(@"%@", request.responseString);
```

This gives me output of `{"errors":{"email":["is already taken"]}}`.

I would like to save email and the message string `"is already taken"` into a string to display in an alert. How can I access those two items into two strings?

Answer (score 4):

The response string is the raw output from the server. In this case it is JSON encoded. You can either use one of the AFNetworking JSON-specific classes (i.e. `AFJSONRequestOperation`) to get the response back as a JSON object, or parse it yourself using `NSJSONSerialization`. I would suggest using `AFJSONRequestOperation`.

Answer (score 1):

```
 NSData *data = [request.responseString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

 id json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
 NSString *str = [[json objectForkey:@"errors"] objectForKey:@"email"][0];
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the following, seems a tiny bit more robust:

```
[requestOperation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:success failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        id response = error.userInfo;
    if (response && [response isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
        NSDictionary *responseDictionary = (NSDictionary *)response;

        // AFNetworking hides the actual error response under this key 
        if ([responseDictionary valueForKey:NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestionErrorKey]) {
            id suggestedRecovery = [responseDictionary valueForKey:NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestionErrorKey];

            if ([suggestedRecovery isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
                // Try to json decode string
                id json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[suggestedRecovery dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:0 error:nil];
                if (json && [json isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
                    responseDictionary = json;
                }
            }
        }

        // .. extract error message out of responseDictionary
    }
    }];
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    NSData *responseData = [[error userInfo] objectForKey:@"data"];
    if ([responseData length] > 0)
    {

     NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData                                                                                encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
      NSLog(@"%@", str);
    }
```